# seed_fu and Rail 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, seeding

I am learning ruby on rails 4 and I came across what initially appeared a perfect alternative for seeding data, seed_fu. It seems way more readable to me. When I went to check it out at github it stated, "The current latest version isn't compatible with Rails 4.0. You will have to use the HEAD of this repo.

gem 'seed-fu', github: 'mbleigh/seed-fu'"

The quoted part seemed to say no I cannot use it, then came the second part, I will have to use the HEAD of the repo. I am still getting used to the concept of installing gems. Does this mean I can use it or not? If I can install it, have you used seed_fu with Rails4? Did it cause any problems?

I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Is that what the purpose of: github: 'mbleigh/seed-fu'"

Comment: Ok, rb I appreciate the help so far but I am new to installing gems. Normally it would be a 'gem install seed_fu. Can a similar thing be done here incorporating the github into the command? I should explain, I need to get this correct without screwing up my existing rails. I have to create a blog as part of a technical job interview. And while I am used to python and django, I am obviously in the learning stages rails.

Comment: perfect, please use that as your answer. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use it with rails 4, provided you specify an additional (github) attribute, so bundler knows where to fetch the gem from. In this case, it will get it from github as opposed to rubygems. Rails 4 version of this gem is probably under development and not yet released, hence you need to get it from github.

Just go to your Gemfile and copy paste that line as it is, run bundle install and you are done.

Comment: Thanks again, i did not get the job. I need to improve my rails skills, and get more experience. I do like rails, and I like a challenge.